# getting core file

Tags: java, aix

I am running a Core JAVA application on AIX machine, and it creates a file named "core".
My concern are
1. I am not able to open this "core" file in "Heap Analyzer" or "Thread Analyzer".
2. Which tools do I need to use, So that I can analyze this "core" file.
3. Could any one elaborate more about this file? why this "core" file creates.

Waiting for response.....
Many Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A [core file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) represents the recorded state of memory of the JVM when it crashed (i.e. **not Java level information** that can be analysed in a profiling tool).  This type of file is indicative of either a bug in the JVM or a problem with a native library that you're calling from within your Java application through JNI.

One command you could run is:

```
strings core | grep JAVA_HOME
```

... which will at least tell you which version of the JVM was running (and hence possibly responsible for the core dump).

You could also try running your application on a different OS or on the same platform but with a different version of the JVM to verify whether that is the cause of the crash.

You might also want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951095/tool-for-analyzing-java-core-dump), where chillitom describes a technique for converting core files to HPROF files in order to analyse them with a Java memory analyser app.  This requires using the `jmap` command line tool; e.g.

```
# jmap -dump:format=b,file=dump.hprof /usr/bin/java core.1234
```