# Node.js Server Timeout Problems (EC2 + Express + PM2)

Tags: node.js, http, express, amazon-ec2, connection-timeout

I'm relatively new to running production node.js apps and I've recently been having problems with my server timing out.

Basically after a certain amount of usage & time my node.js app stops responding to requests. I don't even see routes being fired on my console anymore - it's like the whole thing just comes to a halt and the HTTP calls from my client (iPhone running AFNetworking) don't reach the server anymore. But if I restart my node.js app server everything starts working again, until things inevitable stop again. The app never crashes, it just stops responding to requests.

I'm not getting any errors, and I've made sure to handle and log all DB connection errors so I'm not sure where to start. I thought it might have something to do with memory leaks so I installed **node-memwatch** and set up a listener for memory leaks but that doesn't get called before my server stops responding to requests.

Any clue as to what might be happening and how I can solve this problem?

**Here's my stack:**

- Node.js on AWS EC2 Micro Instance (using Express 4.0 + PM2)
- Database on AWS RDS volume running MySQL (using node-mysql)
- Sessions stored w/ Redis on same EC2 instance as the node.js app
- Clients are iPhones accessing the server via AFNetworking

Once again no errors are firing with any of the modules mentioned above.

Comment: It sounds as if some of your routes are not returning a response and therefore hanging everything else

Answer (score 7):

First of all you need to be a bit more specific about timeouts.

- **TCP timeouts**: TCP divides a message into packets which are sent one by one. The receiver needs to acknowledge having received the packet. If the receiver does not acknowledge having received the package within certain period of time, a TCP retransmission occurs, which is sending the same packet again. If this happens a couple of more times, the sender gives up and kills the connection.
- **HTTP timeout**: An HTTP client like a browser, or your server while acting as a client (e.g: sending requests to other HTTP servers), can set an arbitrary timeout. If a response is not received within that period of time, it will disconnect and call it a timeout.

Now, there are many, many possible causes for this... from more trivial to less trivial:

- **Wrong Content-Length calculation**: If you send a request with a `Content-Length: 20` header, that means "I am going to send you 20 bytes". If you send 19, the other end will wait for the remaining 1. If that takes too long... timeout.
- **Not enough infrastructure**: Maybe you should assign more machines to your application. If `(total load / # of CPU cores)` is over 1, or your memory usage is high, your system may be over capacity. However keep reading...
- **Silent exception**: An error was thrown but not logged anywhere. The request never finished processing, leading to the next item.
- **Resource leaks**: Every request needs to be handled to completion. If you don't do this, the connection will remain open. In addition, the `IncomingMesage` object (aka: usually called `req` in express code) will remain referenced by other objects (e.g: express itself). Each one of those objects can use a lot of memory.
- **Node event loop starvation**: I will get to that at the end.

---

For memory leaks, the symptoms would be:
the node process would be using an increasing amount of memory.

To make things worse, if available memory is low and your server is misconfigured to use swapping, Linux will start moving memory to disk (swapping), which is very I/O and CPU intensive. Servers should not have swapping enabled.

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

will return you the level of swappiness configured in your system (goes from 0 to 100). You can modify it in a persistent way via `/etc/sysctl.conf` (requires restart) or in a volatile way using: `sysctl vm.swappiness=10`

Once you've established you have a memory leak, you need to get a core dump and download it for analysis. A way to do that can be found in this other Stackoverflow response: [Tools to analyze core dump from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704331/tools-to-analyze-core-dump-from-node-js/)

For connection leaks (you leaked a connection by not handling a request to completion), you would be having an increasing number of established connections to your server. You can check your established connections with `netstat -a -p tcp | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l` can be used to count established connections.

Now, the **event loop starvation** is the worst problem. If you have short lived code node works very well. But if you do CPU intensive stuff and have a function that keeps the CPU busy for an excessive amount of time... like 50 ms (50 ms of solid, blocking, synchronous CPU time, not asynchronous code taking 50 ms), operations being handled by the event loop such as processing HTTP requests start falling behind and eventually timing out.

The way to find a CPU bottleneck is using a performance profiler. `nodegrind`/`qcachegrind` are my preferred profiling tools but others prefer flamegraphs and such. However it can be hard to run a profiler in production. Just take a development server and slam it with requests. aka: a load test. There are many tools for this.

---

Finally, another way to debug the problem is:

`env NODE_DEBUG=tls,net node <...arguments for your app>`

node has optional debug statements that are enabled through the `NODE_DEBUG` environment variable. Setting `NODE_DEBUG` to `tls,net` will make node emit debugging information for the tls and net modules... so basically everything being sent or received. If there's a timeout you will see where it's coming from.

**Source:** Experience of maintaining large deployments of node services for years.