# Memory dump using Ping .net

Tags: c#, .net, server, ping, windows

I'm trying to do a ping to a server in a Windows Forms Application but when my program is running, I have memory dump on my computer. Very, very strange.

In my method I only have:

```
private void CheckServer()
{
    this.txResponse.Text = "";

    IPAddress IpAdress = IPAddress.Parse("anAdress");
    Ping ping = new Ping();

    PingReply pingToReply = ping.Send(IpAdress);

    if (pingToReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        txResponse.Text = pingToReply.Status.ToString();
}
```

I really don't understand what is going on.
I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with .NET Framework 4.5 on Windows 8.If it is necessary more information, please let me know.

Comment: do you get the same results when you step through the code running the debugger..?

Comment: did you put a real ip address in for IPAddress.Parse("anAdress"); If not I'd imagine that throws an error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using ping in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800958/using-ping-in-c-sharp) notice from the link how they use `try{}catch{}` you should follow the same structure

Comment: I put this 'cause I don't want to show the ip adress in public. I tested with google's ipadress 66.249.87.104

Comment: Do you have a memory dump, or a memory _leak_?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the parsing of the IP Address is successful; otherwise check the surrounding processing outside of the CheckServer method.

Comment: I tested with the Google IP Address and happened the same

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, the joys of programming having a program blow up when there is absolutely nothing wrong with the code... (your code looks fine other than putting a try/catch block around it)

It could be a hardware issue (memory, disk etc), bad dll, or any number of things that go bump in the night. I assume you have tried rebooting your computer, and pinging your server at the DOS prompt. If not do so.

One thing you could try is to call ping.exe directly with a command line/ip of your choice synchronously or asynchronously, see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25983/How-to-Execute-a-Command-in-C and then parse the output to get what you need (lines starting with "Reply from" or "Request timed out." or even the % loss line.

Another thing to try is bypass the c# `Ping` and `PingReply` calls entirely and use net sockets and a timer, see http://sourceforge.net/projects/pingutil/?source=typ_redirect  particularly the ping.cs file.

These solutions would allow you to potentially write around the problem, but it does not necessarily solve the problem at hand, which does not appear to programming related from the code you have provided.

OK, other thoughts... 1)Do a rebuild all on your project 2) Try compiling using an older version of .NET 3) Create a new project and copy block the source into the newly created files. 4) run the project on another computer to see if you get the same results. Any exception error that may or may not be generated should never cause a core dump.

Yet another option is to analyze the core dump, for an application, see: http://sourceforge.net/projects/core-analyzer/  and also check out
[Tool for analyzing java core dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951095/tool-for-analyzing-java-core-dump)

Worse comes to worse, you may have to reload Visual Studio and/or .NET.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do what you recommend me.