# Java 8 mdmp dump file analyzing with jvisualvm Add VM Coredump grayed / blanked out

Tags: java, jvisualvm

I found [Tool for analyzing java core dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951095/tool-for-analyzing-java-core-dump), which is really close, but when I open up jvisualvm and open "File" menu, the "Add VM Coredump" option is not available. When I run the other option listed in the overflow article I don't get a thread dump. I'm digging into the jmap command a little farther, but I'd like to know how to use the Add VM Coredump feature as it would make life a bit easier.

Comment: Why not use Eclipse Memory Analysis Tool? IMO it is a more mature product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be on Solaris or Linux to access the VisualVM Coredumps option.

In the documentation (http://visualvm.java.net/coredumps.html) it says:

> The Core Dump node is visible in the Applications window if VisualVM is running on Solaris or Linux. Generally, VisualVM can only open a core dump if the core dump was taken on the same machine. A core dump contains informaton on the Java Development Kit (JDK) and kernel of the machine where the core dump was taken. To open the core dump in VisualVM, this information must match the JDK software and kernel of the local system.